# Find all the numbers from the list String and add them and compare if it equals to

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have an page object list element called (number_Check) text value = ($479.00/check).   I have 3 same values. I need to add them and check it equals to a full number $1437.00 == finalnumber element. Could you help me? I tried with regex. I don't know how to compare to final number.

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

String regex = "-?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (int i = 0; i < number_check.size(); i++) {
    String bvalue = number_check.get(i).getAttribute("text");
    String cvalue = number_check.get(1).getAttribute("text");
    String dvalue = number_check.get(2).getAttribute("text");
    String final = finalnumber.getAttribute("text");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(bvalue);
    Matcher c = p.matcher(cvalue);
    Matcher d = p.matcher(dvalue);
    double sum = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        mylist.add(m.group(0));
        mylist.add(c.group(0));
        mylist.add(d.group(0));
        sum += Double.parseDouble(m.group(0) + c.group(0) + d.group(0));
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: you can't use `final` as a variable identifier. It's a Java keyword. Maybe you mean `final String noKeywordVariableName = finalnumber.getAttribute("text");`

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. You should be more specific to your queries. Your code is so confusing. Please provide more information.

Comment: number_check = page object  and I'm trying to loop to get the value with regex and add the numbers together.

Comment: I meant full number = finalnumber.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code and you don't need regex to do this. Here's a simpler version.

```
double actual = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < number_check.size(); i++)
{
    actual += getDoubleFromString(number_check.get(i).getAttribute("text"));
}
double expected = getDoubleFromString(finalnumber.getAttribute("text"));

Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
```

...and since you are likely to reuse this a lot, I wrote a function to convert the string to a double after stripping out the non-numbers.

```
public static double getDoubleFromString(String s)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(s.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
}
```

Comment: I don't know why we need String s in parameters. If we are adding  number_check together and comparing to final number if it equals.

Comment: SO you would put String s =  "$1437.00"

Comment: No, the parameter is used when the function is called from elsewhere. The code that gets the text from your element `.getAttribute("text")` is passed into that function as a `String`, gets processed, and is returned as a double. The function just turns some string like `($479.00/check)` into a double 479.00.

Comment: How would you call it. class v = new class(); v.getDoubleFromString(): s =?. I'm confused.

Comment: It's in the code above. The second block of code is just the function.

Comment: public double getDoubleFromString(String s) {
  

  double actual = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < textview_price.size(); i++)
  {
      actual += getDoubleFromString(textview_price.get(i).getAttribute("text"));
  }
  double expected = getDoubleFromString(AnnualPrice.getAttribute("text"));

  Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
  Log.log(driver).info("Finished Counting pass");
  
  return Double.parseDouble(s.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));

Comment: I don't understand. The first block of code in my answer replaces all of your code. The second block of code is a function that the first block of my code calls.

Comment: How would I run it from different class. I''m confused about parameter String s.

Comment: Could you remove parameter?

Comment: You need to spend some time working through some basic programming tutorials so that you can understand this code. This is not overly complex code. I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Still won't add up actual do you know why? I tried  i=I+1. The actual number is not adding up.

Comment: @jackdaniel I don't know what you are referring to. Why are we referring to `i=I+1`? What does that have to do with my answer or your question?

Comment: i = i + 1; I meant to Jeff

Comment: @jackdaniel That still doesn't explain what you are referring to. Where in my answer or your question was this referred to?

Comment: It says it should be $1437.0 but answer is $479.0 on actual. The list does not gets looped it.

Comment: @jackdaniel That's something wrong with the locator you are using or the collection `number_check`.